# Firebase authentication, function createUserWithEmailAndPassword dosent execute

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase with Android to register a user and insert its data into a DB.
I have 3 classes, the fragment class that gets all the data from the user - > send the object to Model class - > UserModelFirebase

This is the hierarchy of the project.

This is the code:

SignUpFragment

```
    public void SignUp(){
        User newUser = new User(txtEmail.getText().toString(),
            txtPassword.getText().toString(),
            false);

    String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

    Model.instance.addUser(newUser, password, new Model.IAddUser() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(User user) {
            MusicPostListFragment listFragment = MusicPostListFragment.newInstance(1);
            onButtonPressed(listFragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String reason) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Unable to create user, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
}
```

Model

```
public class Model {
private ModelUserFirebase modelUserFirebase;
public final static Model instance = new Model();

private Model(){
    modelUserFirebase = new ModelUserFirebase();
       }

public interface IAddUser {
    void onComplete(User user);
    void onError(String reason);
}
public void addUser(User user, String password, final IAddUser callback ) {
    modelUserFirebase.addUser(user, password, new ModelUserFirebase.IAddUser() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(User user) {
            callback.onComplete(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String reason) {
            callback.onError(reason);
        }
    });
}
```

UserModelFirebase

```
public class ModelUserFirebase {

private static final String USERS_KEY = "Users";
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference usersReference;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

private User currentUser;

public ModelUserFirebase() {
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    usersReference = database.getReference(USERS_KEY);
}

interface IAddUser {
    void onComplete(User user);
    void onError(String reason);
}
public void addUser(final User user, String password, final IAddUser callback) {
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), "123456Ee!")
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("dev","createUserWithEmail: onComplete()");
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = task.isSuccessful() ?
                            firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() : null;

                    if (firebaseUser != null) {
                        User savedUser = new User(user);
                        savedUser.setId(firebaseUser.getUid());
                        usersReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(savedUser);
                        callback.onComplete(savedUser);
                    }
                    else {
                        callback.onError(task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

What is happening?
when I debug the code, I see that after the line of addOnCompleteListener
nothing happened, nor onComplete onError

Comment: It runs in a separate thread. Android Studio debugger view will show multiple threads

Comment: Why do you have two interfaces with the exact same signatures?

Comment: @cricket_007 each interface in a different class, this is the hierarchy that the lecture demands -_- . The interface in Model class calls to the UserModelFirebase.

Comment: @cricket_007 so how can I check why it doesn't work? cause now the database is empty, and I don't get any exceptions

Comment: I would suggest reducing your problem set to not have so many layers of redirection. The "model"  only stores data, and the Controller performs actions for creation of the model. For reference, `Model.instance` nor `modelUserFirebase` are not defined in your question, so your code is difficult to follow

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your attention, I edit the post

Comment: If you put `firebaseAuth` directly in the Fragment, what happens?

Comment: @cricket_007 same problem... it just skipping all the code after that line addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()   and nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean "skipping"? It's asynchronous. It won't run immediately after that line

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean that I don't get a success message and not an error message.. nothing was inserted to the firebase server

Comment: At least `Log.d("dev"` should be ran. I don't know what else to tell you

Comment: @cricket_007 I saw now, the error is "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."

Comment: There you go :) Now, either your internet permissions are failing, or there's something blocking you from reaching Firebase